# Maintaining data with factories in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I have the next issue. I have two jsp, the first one sets a value in a variable that I want to use on mi second view, I want to do it using factories, mi's problem is that the first view set the value correctly, but when I want to recover it on the second, it's undefined. I have researched, but I cannot find the answer can anybody help me.

That is my first view.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3   /angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Services.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="Modulo" ng-controller="controladorForm">
<div class="form">

    <label for="nombre">AgregaNombre</label> 
    <input id="nombre" ng-model="nombre" type="text" />
    <button id="addBtn" class="btn" ng-click="add()">Añadir</button>
</div>
<div>{{nombreFac}}</div>
<a href="PresentaDatos.jsp">PresentaDatos</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**services.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Modulo', []);

app.factory('Factoria',function(){


var regreso = {};

return{ getSaludo : function(nombre) {
        regreso = nombre;
        alert(regreso);
        return regreso;
    },getData : function(){
        return regreso;
    }
    }
return regreso;

});



app.controller("controladorForm", ['$scope','Factoria', function($scope,Factoria){

$scope.add = function(){
    $scope.nombreFac = Factoria.getSaludo($scope.nombre);
}

$scope.get = function(){
     $scope.nombreFac = Factoria.getData();
}


}
]);


 app.controller("controladorPresenta", ['$scope','$rootScope','Factoria',     function($scope,$rootScope,Factoria){
 $scope.nombreFac = Factoria.getData();
 alert(Factoria.getData());
}
]);
```

**mi second view**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Services.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-app="Modulo" ng-controller="controladorPresenta">
<!-- <button id="addBtn" class="btn" ng-click="get()">Obtener</button> -->
{{nombreFac}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only works in a SPA (single page app). You are loading different pages which have different instances of the factory. Note you are also using outdated `<DOCTYPE>`

Comment: To echo @charlietfl, you are reloading your angular app from scratch as you navigate to the other page. Therefore it does not have the previous instance of your factory, it has a new one. You need to use angular routing to navigate from page to page instead of doing full post backs on each page.

Comment: Thank you very much for yours answers, your solved my misunderstanding